# Failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-core v0.34.0`

Tags: libp2p

Compile successfully on mac, but it fails to compile on linux.

repo: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

system: linux(centos)

error log:

```bash
   Compiling sp-panic-handler v4.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)
error: failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-core v0.34.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/ssm-user/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/libp2p-core-9ce8bf6b64c36b1a/build-script-build` (exit status:101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: Other, error: "protoc failed: envelope.proto:1:10: Unrecognized syntaxidentifier \"proto3\".  This parser only recognizes \"proto2\".\n" }', /home/ssm-user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libp2p-core-0.34.0/build.rs:30:6
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing/building with `--locked`, the process will then use the dependency versions from the `Cargo.lock` file in the repository. Those dependencies are typically verified to work. If you omit the `--locked` you'll get potentially newer versions of the dependencies that could introduce some incompatibility.

If this doesn't work: seeing the `proto2` vs `proto3` error message, could also be that your local version of `protoc` is outdated. Try `protoc --version` to see what you have installed.
Are you possibly using an old version in your environment? I'd check if there are updates available for your operating system then.

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same error
To find out more about `protoc`
Just run `protoc --version`
It will tell you it is not found.
This will be the output

```
Command 'protoc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install protobuf           # version 3.14.0, or
sudo apt  install protobuf-compiler  # version 3.12.4-1ubuntu7.22.04.1
See 'snap info protobuf' for additional versions.
```

With it, it gives solutions of what to do, so I took `sudo apt  install protobuf-compiler` And the next time I ran my `cargo build` command, it worked well.